# Doesn't "Alien vs Predator" contradict the previous movies with regards to Predators and their relation to heat?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator, predator-series, predator

In *Predator*, the girl reveals that the "devil" (the Predator) only comes in the "hottest of years". In the beginning of *Predator 2*, there is a newscast in the background that states that LA is experiencing an unprecedented heat wave.

This creates 2 possible plot holes in *AvP*:

1. It appears that the Predators prefer hot weather, but in *AvP* they don't mind the extreme cold even without any cold weather gear.
2. In *AvP* it's suggested that when the Predators build the pyramid in Antarctica, the climate there was mild, even maybe hot. However, Antarctica has been covered by ice for the last 23 million years. But 23 million years ago, the modern humans seen in the pyramid would have not existed, thus the plot hole.

Is there an explanation offered anywhere in the *Predator* universe for this?

Comment: Plot holes in AvP?  Go figure.. ;)

Comment: Is there a question here, or just an observation?

Comment: Maybe the Predators know hunting humans will be better in hot years as humans can struggle with heat. It could be that hunting aliens is best done in the cold.

Comment: “It appears that the predators prefer hot weather” — that could easily be coincidence. “it's suggested that when the predators build the pyramid in Antarctica, the climate there was mild, even maybe hot” Is it? When?

Comment: @Adeptus : I guess I'm asking if an explanation to these discrepancies was ever given anywhere in the predator universe?

Comment: There's a big difference between preferring something and not being able to survive in other conditions.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - I think it's more then mere coincidence, I think it's strongly suggested by the first 2 movies and how the predator looks. Large bodies also suggest warm climate.

Comment: @ventsyv: “it's strongly suggested by... how the predator looks”. How so? “Large bodies also suggest warm climate.” Predators aren’t that much bigger than humans, and we live in colder climates just fine.

Comment: Actors Kevin Peter Hall (7 feet 2 inches) and Ian Whyte (7 feet 1 inch) played the predator in Predator 1/2 and AvP.

Answer (score 4):

The bigger plot hole in *AvP* was that they arrived at an antarctic whaling station and drilled down a [2000ft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_%28film%29#Plot) to reach the temple. The temple was supposedly built before the ice pushed over it, so imagine winding back time, all that ice melted and the temple revealed. Wouldn't the sea level go up from our current sea level. That temple would be deeep under the sea.

I guess you could imagine the the whole earth tilted and somehow Africa was covered in ice while the Antarctic where they drilled was somehow exposed and the water levels went down 2000ft.

There's your climate related plot hole. As for the Predators liking hot or cold. I wouldn't consider that a plot hole.

Maybe the Jungle Girl only saw them when it was hot because they just dislike the in between temperatures of mild day in the jungle or warm day at the arctic.

Another possibility is the Predators like to test themselves in the most extreme environments on earth. Jungle Girl only saw them because in cold years they were off hunting Eskimo skulls.

Or maybe Predators are like humans, some like it hot, some like it cold. If you consider the second *AvP* movie, they even flat out state there are different types of Predator that don't like each other.

Comment: Antarctica is a land mass, the ice accumulated through snow fall, if it melts, the water level will rise but it the temple is at high elevation, it might not reach it.

Comment: @ventsyv Yeah, the temple being at elevation would explain if it only someone in special effects hadn't said "Wouldn't it be cool if the alien queen burst through all these whale bones!" Did the whalers drag the whales up the mountain from the sea?

Comment: Hmm, maybe there was some sort of shield protecting the temple from the water? This would also work as a sort of final protection in case if aliens would win. There is a mention, that the temple had some huge power source, if my memory is right... But hey, I am just throwing a [voodo shark](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VoodooShark) here